# Global Variables in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, railo, application.cfc

2 Questions -

In CF8 in the application.cfm I cold set a global variable 
like so

```
<cfset DSN = "dej6_42">
```

I am now trying to adjust to the Application.cfc in CF10/Lucee and can not figure out how to set this same variable.

Here is my current Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent output="false"> 

    <cfset This.name = "My Application"> 
    <cfset This.clientmanagement="True"> 
    <cfset This.loginstorage="Session"> 
    <cfset This.sessionmanagement="True"> 
    <cfset This.sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,0,10,0)#"> 
    <cfset This.applicationtimeout="#createtimespan(5,0,0,0)#">

    <cfset DSN = "dej6_42">
</cfcomponent>
```

I have tried

```
<cfset This.DSN = "dej6_42">
```

Then tried to call in a separate page

```
<cfoutput>#Applicaton.DSN#</cfoutput>
```

I think from my research I will need to use both application.cfc and application.cfm to accomplish the above.  *edit - I tried to add an include at the end of the application.cfc file to applciation.cfm and it did not work.

2 Question.
When I place any of the standard functions in the Application.cfc my site turns to a blank page

Here is that Application.cfc - I if I remove everything below the DSN set then it will display the site.

```
<cfcomponent output="false"> 

    <cfset This.name = "My Application"> 
    <cfset This.clientmanagement="True"> 
    <cfset This.loginstorage="Session"> 
    <cfset This.sessionmanagement="True"> 
    <cfset This.sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,0,10,0)#"> 
    <cfset This.applicationtimeout="#createtimespan(5,0,0,0)#">

    <cfset DSN = "dej6_42">

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart"> 

    </cffunction> 

    <cffunction name="onApplicationEnd"> 

    </cffunction> 


    <cffunction name="onRequestStart">  

    </cffunction> 

    <cffunction name="onRequest"> 

    </cffunction> 


    <cffunction name="onRequestEnd"> 

    </cffunction> 

    <cffunction name="onSessionStart"> 

    </cffunction> 

    <cffunction name="onSessionEnd"> 

    </cffunction> 

    <cffunction name="onError"> 

    </cffunction> 



</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Matt's answer is correct. CFC's have their own variables scope that is not shared with the rest of the request.  This is by design and desirable or encapsulation. Also, note the "application" scope in no way references any variables set in any scope in the Application.cfc. Also, read the docs on Application.cfc, you're intercepting your request with empty methods.

Comment: You might want to give this a read: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/ as it explains these lifecycle methods

Answer (score 5):

Your example doesn't set a global variable. It sets a variable in the variables scope: it will not be accessible to any CFC-based code nor any custom tags used within the request. It'll only be available in the Application.cfm, the file requested, files it includes, and OnRequestEnd.cfm

Application.cfc is a CFC (to state the obvious), so variables-scoped variables set within it are only available within it. If you want to set an application-wide variable, you need to put it in the application scope. Application scope variables should be set in the `onApplicationStart)` handler which is run once when the application starts, but not on every request. By way of comparison Application.cfm (which is misnamed) is run on every request. It should be called OnRequestStart.cfm.

So to be clear, setting an application-scoped variable in `onApplicationStart` would be as thus:

```
function onApplicationStart() {
    application.DSN = "dej6_42";
}
```

If you use an `onRequest()` interceptor, and within that `include` the originally requested file, then the request will be run in the context of the Application.cfc instance, and variables set within `onRequest` will be available to the rest of the mainline request code, much like the way you set your variable in Application.cfm. Semantically though, if you mean a variable to exist for the life of the application (like a DSN), then putting it in the application scope is the best bet.

It sounds to me from the inferences one can make from your question that your app architecture might be languishing in the 1990s. I think you should read up on using a framework (eg: [FW/1](https://github.com/framework-one/fw1) or [ColdBox](http://www.coldbox.org/)) to better organise your code in a maintainable and scalable way.

Also you should read up on [Application.cfc](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Defining+the+application+and+its+event+handlers+in+Application.cfc) (and [method reference](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Application.CFC+Reference)). And probably CFCs in general: [Using ColdFusion components-Developing guide](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+ColdFusion+components-Developing+guide).

You also might want to think about modernising your approach to writing CFML and spare the tags for view code, and otherwise using script. It makes the code easier to follow for both you and other developers who might end up needing to maintain it if the whole app isn't cluttered up with tags.

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean - modernising your approach to writing CFML and spare the tags for view code, and otherwise using script.

Comment: Nix that last comment Adam. I re-read what you wrote. Yes I agree, this is just at attempt at Application.cfc. I support a tag based system so that is what I am comfortable using and we use application.cfm- and this cfc is a different creature, but I am not opposed to change.  Its harder in that environment since its more code support then major changes where re-writes are required. Its an adventure for sure since the developer liked to hard code stuff rather then use variables.

Comment: one snippet would be nice

Comment: An example of setting a variable? Really? OK, I'll update the answer. Done.

Comment: Mark, I feel for you.  I've been stuck with 2 of those.  And learned cold fusion tags by learning to maintain them.  I wasn't until I saw another bit of code using cfc's that I found out that ColdFusion wasn't actually still a tag based language.  And, like you, the guy I took it over from hard coded stuff and didn't even use all the tools available in ColdFusion tags.  He would build these 30 to 40 lines of code ways to do some stuff like DateAdd and then cut and paste them EVERYWHERE!!!. It's amazing what some people get away with. Oh yea, and I am NOT comfortable with tags. They are aweful

Answer (score 3):

You need to set it into the application scope

```
<cfcomponent output="false"> 
  <cfset This.name = "My Application"> 
  <cfset This.clientmanagement="True"> 
  <cfset This.loginstorage="Session"> 
  <cfset This.sessionmanagement="True"> 
  <cfset This.sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(0,0,10,0)#"> 
  <cfset This.applicationtimeout="#createtimespan(5,0,0,0)#">
  <cfset application.DSN = 'dej6_42'>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error stating Element DSN is undefined in application.

Comment: That's the wrong place to set an application scope variable. It should be within `onApplicationStart()`