# Save user selections for a web application using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cookies, coldfusion

I am building a web application using ColdFusion and traditional web technologies (html, css and javascript).

I have 2 divs:

Div one contains a table that is updated through Ajax and pulls information from sql server (a list of documents that the user can select one by one).As the user is selecting rows, I want them to be shown in the 2nd div (so the user can see what has been selected).

When a user selects a row I pass the data for that selection to a javascript function that updates the 2nd div with ajax. Obviously with this approach I can only send information for a single row (the one selected).

My doubt is, how can I keep track of all the items selected so the 2nd div can show all of them and not the only one that is being selected? Should I use cookies to save them? What other option I may have? Below an image of the application

Application layout:

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why does the server need to know about the selections as they are made (i.e. why is AJAX involved)? Is the server formatting the div 2 contents or something? What exactly is the problem, getting more than 1 selected row in the box at a time (e.g. is each selection replacing the one before)? Code example would be useful.

Comment: Sorry, don't have the code with me right now, but will upload it as soon as I can. Yes, a coldfusion template is in charge of formatting div's 2 content and also Yes, the selected item is being replaced when choosing another one and I want them to stack on top of each other. Thanks

Comment: Is you AJAX currently using `.innerHTML` to add the response data to DIV 2?

Do you want your server to resend all selected rows each time a new row is added or just the most recently added row? Basically, how sound do you want the application level to be?

Comment: For ajax I am using jquery, pointing to the div by its ID '$("#xmlSelected").html(data);'. The idea is that if the user selects 5 items, all 5 must be shown in the 2nd div (where they can be removed too with the littlle red closing icon); when the user finishes I can work in the next page with all selected items

Comment: I have applications with pretty much the exact setup. I usually have the server send all of the selected IDs to make sure the application stays synchronized. You'll need sessions and session variables or a database to keep track of this on the server side. Alternatively, you can store the state on the client side. Use the jquery equivalent to `.insertAdjacentHTML` for each new return data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to save data that it is accessible from your client side application, but it depends on your current architecture. A few that come to mind:

- Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you want to persist the values on the same browser. This will not communicate with the backend: `localStorage.setItem('selectedItems', JSON.stringify(selectedItemsArray));`
- Use a global variable namespaced by your application. For example: `window.myApp = {}; window.myApp.selectedItems = [...]`
- Use [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) , a database that lives in your Browser.

Because you are using the ColdFusion framework, you may be limited in the options. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133251/3244654) describes how to add application scoped variables.